# PyQt5: why am I only able to use two colours for QTableWidget cells?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

So I am trying to colour my QTableWidget QTableWidgetItems depending on the item.text(). This is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

class Table(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(9)
        self.setRowCount(1)
        self.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem('A'))
        self.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem('B'))
        self.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem('C'))
        self.setItem(0, 3, QTableWidgetItem('D'))
        self.setItem(0, 4, QTableWidgetItem('E'))
        self.setItem(0, 5, QTableWidgetItem('F'))
        self.setItem(0, 6, QTableWidgetItem('A'))
        self.setItem(0, 7, QTableWidgetItem('C'))
        self.setItem(0, 8, QTableWidgetItem('D'))

        for r in range(self.rowCount()):
            for c in range(self.columnCount()):
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                self.item(r, c).setBackground(self.colour(self.item(r, c).text()))

    def colour(self, letter):

        if letter == 'A':
            colour = QColor(233, 12, 24)
        if letter == 'B':
            colour = QColor(12, 45, 67)
        if letter in ['C', 'E']:
            colour = QColor(23, 57, 188)
        if letter == 'F':
            colour = QColor(45, 116, 75)
        else:
            colour = QColor(233, 244, 12)
        return colour

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(200,200,1200,400)
    tw = Table(window)
    twLayout = QVBoxLayout()
    twLayout.addWidget(tw)
    window.setLayout(twLayout)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it, only two colours end up in my table, and the rest get ignored. How can I fix it and how can I make sure that each cell gets its individual colour based on its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of `Table.colour` you have multiple `if` statements but the `else` clause will only match the last of those.  You want...

```
def colour(self, letter):
    if letter == 'A':
        colour = QColor(233, 12, 24)
    elif letter == 'B':
        colour = QColor(12, 45, 67)
    elif letter in ['C', 'E']:
        colour = QColor(23, 57, 188)
    elif letter == 'F':
        colour = QColor(45, 116, 75)
    else:
        colour = QColor(233, 244, 12)
    return colour
```